# Finding the gradient with directional derivatives.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm working on this problem:

Given are two directional derivatives of a function $f(x,y)$ at the point $P$. The first one is in the direction of $u=-4i+5j$ and is equal to $\sqrt{41}$ and the second one is in the direction of $v= 9i + 2j$ and is equal to $\sqrt{85}$.

So I'm trying to find the gradient but I don't know what the point $P$ is and the function $f(x,y)$.

I've read through the whole chapter in my textbook discussing the topic but I can't make sense of the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You’re missing a key assumption in the problem statement. Is the function differentiable at $P$? If not, then there’s nothing you can say about its gradient given those two directional derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the gradient $(f_x, f_y)$ at the point $P$. The two unit vectors along the two given directions are
$(-\frac4{\sqrt{41}},\frac5{\sqrt{41}})$ and $(\frac9{\sqrt{85}},\frac2{\sqrt{85}})$, respectively. Then, match the two directional derivatives to get

$$(f_x, f_y)\cdot(-\frac4{\sqrt{41}},\frac5{\sqrt{41}})=\sqrt{41},\>\>\>\>\>(f_x, f_y)\cdot(\frac9{\sqrt{85}},\frac2{\sqrt{85}})=\sqrt{85}$$

or,

$$-4f_x+5f_y=41,\>\>\>\>\>9f_x+2f_y=85$$

Then, solve to obtain the gradient.

Comment: So I find the value of `fx` and `fy` and that's everything ?

Comment: @matens - that is the gradient of f(x,y)